# Can't get basic nix home manager setup working

Tags: nix

I've followed the instructions in the manual exactly, but am getting an error.

I've run the following as specified:

```bash
$ nix-channel --add
https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager/archive/master.tar.gz
home-manager
$ nix-channel --update
$ export NIX_PATH=$HOME/.nix-defexpr/channels:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels${NIX_PATH:+:$NIX_PATH}
$ nix-shell '<home-manager>' -A install
$ source $HOME/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/hm-session-vars.sh
```

I then modified `home.nix` in line with the example in the manual:

```hs
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  home.username = "jamesflight";
  home.homeDirectory = "/home/jamesflight";

  home.packages = [                               1
    pkgs.htop
    pkgs.fortune
  ];

  home.stateVersion = "22.11";

  programs.home-manager.enable = true;
}
```

When I run `home-manager switch` or `home-manager build` I get the
following error:

```
error: A definition for option `home.packages."[definition 6-entry 1]"' is not of type `package'. Definition values:
       - In `/home/jamesflight/.config/nixpkgs/home.nix': 1
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

I've even tried reinstalling nix to see if it was some global nix
issue, but that hasn't helped.

Any insight anyone can shed on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> { config, pkgs, ... }:
>
> {
> home.username = "jamesflight";
> home.homeDirectory = "/home/jamesflight";
>
> home.packages = [                               1
> pkgs.htop
> pkgs.fortune
> ];
>
> home.stateVersion = "22.11";
>
> programs.home-manager.enable = true;
> }

Please note that the *home.packages* definition starts with the numeral `1`, which is what the error is complaining about.